# Background image overflows to the container above

Tags: html, css

I have two two containers, a navigation bar and the hero below it. I only set background-image for the hero and I have no background-image set for the navigation bar. However, the background for the navigation bar seems to be set automatically the same as the hero.[image]

Part of my css looks like below:

```
 .Nav {
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .HeroWrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("images/pencil.jpg");
  background-size: 100px;
  }
```

and my html is like:

```
<div class = "Nav"></div>
<div class = "HeroWrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the `position` values of both of your divs (`fixed` and `relative`).

It looks like `.Nav` has a transparent background by default. If you do not want `.Nav` to have this background you could simply specify another such as `background: white;`

```
.Nav {
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
    background: white
  }
```